# How to restrict the comment form in wordpress by users' roles?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am setting up a wordpress website where I have only two relevant user groups/roles (Founder and Premium). I would like to restrict ALL the users, except from FOUNDERS and ADMINS, from commenting posts.
To sum up, Founders and Admins can see and add comments, while all the other users can only see them.

I have almost 0 knowledge about PHP, and I know a bit of CSS. I have tried a couple of different code snippets in my child theme function.php, but none of them seem to work properly. The following snippet for example, does close the comments' form, but for all the users. I would like it to be open for founders and admins.

```
add_action( 'init', function()
{
    $u = wp_get_current_user();

    if( $u->exists() && in_array( 'founder', (array) $u->roles, true ) )
        return;

    add_filter( 'comments_open', '__return_false' );
} );
```

Again, I expect that founders and admins can comment, while other users can just read comments. I tried to restrict the comment form, but it gets closed for all users.

Thanks in advance for you time and help.

Comment: If you hook it on `init`, this function will run every time the script is loaded. I would not put that unnecessary strain on the already slow WP engine. Instead, why don't you: 1. show/hide the comment box depending on the user role; 2. To add extra safeguard, hook a function to `comment_post` to verify the user level before recording the comment.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I thought about showing/hiding the comment box, however, if I do that, I am also gonna hide the comments which I want to show. I only what to hide the form which is in the comment widget. Do you have a suggestion on how to show/hide the form based on user role? If that is easier, then I'll opt for that.